# plesk host multiple site with common API

Tags: node.js, server, plesk

I'm very new to plesk and having a hard time trying to understand how it works.

I have three Signle Page App (SPA) and one API. All three SPAs needs to communicate with the common api.

I have created three different individual "domain" for three SPA and now stuck on API.

For the API (running on nodejs), I created a different domain inside plesk and API is running on port 8001.

I tried to nginx proxypass from SAP domain, but all shows 502?

Has anyone hosted multiple site on plesk with a common API?
Is this the right way or am I doing it all wrong?